# Query to purge certain records

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, so table 1 contains a list of users with an associated ID number. It also contains an "inactive" field (I'll reference this below). Table 2 shows a list of reports that have been filled out, which records the user's report and also that unique ID.

What I want to do is select reports that are older than 30 days. If the user has not filled out a report in that time frame, I want to set their status in table 1 as "inactive."

My biggest challenge has been that there are numerous reports with the same ID number being returned. I don't know how to get these into an array or anything without duplication.

I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Can you provide a sql fiddle with an example? it would be easiyer to work on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're looking for a list of `user_id` values for users who have no reports less than 30 days old. You want to use that list in an `UPDATE` query to set those users `inactive`.

The list:

```
       SELECT u.user_id
         FROM user u
    LEFT JOIN report r  ON r.user_id = u.user_id
                       AND r.reportdate < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
        WHERE r.user_id IS NULL
```

This is the `LEFT JOIN  ... IS NULL` pattern for finding right-side rows that do not match the left-side JOIN criterion.

Once you've got that worked out (hey! check it and make sure it's right!) you can use it in your UPDATE query:

```
 UPDATE user 
    SET status='inactive'
  WHERE user_id IN (
       SELECT u.user_id
         FROM user u
    LEFT JOIN report r  ON r.user_id = u.user_id
                       AND r.reportdate < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
        WHERE r.user_id IS NULL
  )
```